# error Unable to create converter for java utilizando kotlin-retrofit- compose

Tags: retrofit, serialización

Estaba desarrollando una App en Android, en la que he intentado implementar una llamada a un endpoint de una api concreta y al compilar la aplicacion me arroja el error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for java.util.List<com.example.marsphotos.network.MarsPhoto>for method getPhotos
:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.